# Dimension of intersection of real analytic sets

Tags: real-analysis, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, real-analytic-structures

Suppose that $A,B$ are real analytic subsets of $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p\in A\cap B \neq \emptyset$. Does the intersection inequality from complex analysis still hold, i.e. does the following inequality hold:

$\mathrm{dim}^{\mathbb{R}}_p(A\cap B) \geq \mathrm{dim}^{\mathbb{R}}_p(A)+\mathrm{dim}^{\mathbb{R}}_p( B)-n$?

By real analytic subset, I mean sets that are locally given as the zero set of finitely manly real analytic functions and by dimension, I mean the maximal dimension of regular points near $p$ as manifolds. The complex analytic proofs that I know use the "Active Lemma", i.e. $\mathrm{dim}(\left\{f=0\right\})=n-1$, for non-zero $f$, which does not hold over $\mathbb{R}$.

If not, are there explicit counterexamples?

Comment: I don't fully understand your definition of dimension, so can I get an example: if you look at the set defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $z^2 - x^2 - y^2 = 0$ (so a bi-cone), what is its dimension at the origin? (is it 2?)

Comment: (If the dimension is 2, then you have a counterexample by intersecting the bi-cone with the plane $z = 0$ which is two dimensional.)

Comment: A simpler example is a sphere in three space and a plane tangent to it .

Comment: @MohanRamachandran you might as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a counterexample take a sphere in 3 space and a plane tangent to it .